# Finding a string from a text file, from bottom

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to find a certain string, in a text file, from bottom (the end of the line).
Once the string has been found, the function exit.

Here is my code, which is working fine. But, it is kind of slow.
I meant, I run this code every 5 seconds. And it consumes about 0.5% to 1% CPU time.
The text file is about 10 MB.

How to speed this up? Like, really fast and it doesn't consume much CPU time.

```
function TMainForm.GetVMem: string;
var
  TS: TStrings;
  sm: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  TS := TStringList.Create;
  TS.LoadFromFile(LogFileName);
  for i := TS.Count-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    sm := Trim(TS[i]);
    if Pos('Virtual Memory Total =', sm) > 0 then
    begin
      Result := sm;
      TS.Free;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := '';
  TS.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Not related to performance, but you really must put a `try..finally` in there to protect the `TStringList` object. And, at the same time, you need to remove the in-loop `TS.Free`. Also, you really need to get rid of the `Application.ProcessMessages`; that's an anti-pattern (and it will slow down the routine!). If this routine slows down the GUI too much (without the A.PM), put it in a different thread.

Comment: Putting `Application.ProcessMessages` into a function is plain wrong. I suppose it is there in order to keep the application responsive during the call, but that is a bad solution.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Yes, I removed the Application.ProcessMessages and also added try .. except to catch any error.

Comment: You can  use TParallel.For.  The document is here,http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TParallel.For_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library Edit: I saw delphi-7 tag. this function doesn't exist in delphi-7

Comment: 10MB is a pretty small file on today's computers, and 0.5-1% CPU is nothing. That performance is absolutely fine. What specific problem are you having? Are you running on an antique computer with a very slow processor and hardly any RAM?

Comment: You don't want to use try except here. You don't want to catch exceptions. You can't do anything useful with them here. It's try finally. Like Andreas said. Read closely his comment.

Comment: break; is easier to use here than exit;

Comment: @Greg I think exit is correct, because the result has been assigned, but what is needed is that try/finally

Comment: @Dave, yes Exit will work, but more often then not I'll use Break to exit a loop when I find my thing, especially if I have more to do in my proc.  So for me it is a more familiar pattern, easier to follow, less chance for error.  Exit can work too, especially with a try...finally block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TMemoryStream and use LoadFromFile to load the complete file content.

The you can cast the property Memory to either PChar or PAnsiChar or other character type depending on file content.

When you have the pointer, you can use it to check for content. I would avoid using string handling because it is much slower than pointer operation.

You can move the pointer from the end of memory (use Stream.Size) and search backward for the CR/LF pair (or whatever is used as line delimiter). Then from that point check for the searched string. If found, you are done, if not, loop searching the previous CR/LF.

That is more complex than the method you used but - if done correctly - will be faster.

If the file is to big to fit in memory, specially in a x32 application, you'll have to resort to read the file line by line, keeping only one line, going to the end of file. Each time you find the searched string, then save his position. At the end of file, this saved position - if any - will be the last searched file.

If the file is really very large, and the probability that the searched string is near the end, you may read the file backward (Setting TStream.position to have direct access). block by block. Then is each block, use the previous algorithm. Pay attention that the searched string may be split in two blocks depending on the block size.

Again, depending on the file size, you may split the search in several parallel searches using multi threading. Do not create to much thread neither. Pay attention that the searched string may be split in two blocks assigned to different threads depending on the block size.

Comment: This will likely be slower than the code in the question, certainly not algorithmically better.